# Definir altura para UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Estou criando uma aplicação para `iOS` utilizando `Swift`, estou tendo muita dificuldade em relação a altura da `UIScrollView`, estou usando `auto-layout` e  crio a seguinte estrutura:

- UIScrollView

  - UIView // View onde insiro os componentes

    - UIImageView // Constraint Top Edges 20 em relação á UIView
    - UITextView // Constraint Top Edges 40 em relação á UIImageView
    - UITextView // Constraint Top Edges 20 em relação á UITextView
    - UIButton // Constraint Top Edges 30 em relação ao UIButton

Atualmente estou utilizando a seguinte lógica para calcular a altura para a `UIScrollView`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var scrollHeight : CGFloat = 0.0

    for view in self.containerView.subviews {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        scrollHeight += view.frame.size.height
    }

    // Adicionar o tamanho da scrollview, de acordo com a soma
    // das alturas das views filhas
    self.scrollView.contentSize.height = scrollHeight

}
```

Porém consigo apenas obter a altura dos itens, sem calcular os espaços criados pelas `constraints`. Gostaria de saber alguma forma de definir a altura para a `UIScrollView` com precisão.

Answer (score 2):

Tente:

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```